# has_many relationship with images in the def create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, has-many, belongs-to

I am trying to create many images for a single product.
Since the number of images per product is as many as the user wants to enter I have created 2 separate models, product and product_image.
Product has many product_images
and product_images belongs_to product

I'm almost certain that this section of code is the problem (this is the product_image controller)

```
def create
  @product_image = ProductImage.new(params[:product_image])
  @product = @product_image.product

 if @product_image.save
  @product_image.product_id = @product.id
  @product_image.save

  redirect_to @product_image, notice: 'Product image was successfully created.'         
 else
  render :template => "products/edit"       
 end
end
```

At the moment the code allows me to upload an image via paperclip but totally disregards the product_id and just puts the product_image_id in that field instead.

I checked the db through the cmd line to see this.

So how do I get an image to be created with an ID of a particular product? I've searched this site but the questions that exist do seem to offer the solution that I require.
Thanks for any help you can offer.

Here are the migrations that I used for the models relating to products and product_images

I apologize for the mess, I was very indecisive in my initial development which caused lost of little changes to be made as I gained more knowledge about the whole rails system

products

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :products do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.text :description
    t.string :image_url
    t.decimal :price, precision: 8, scale: 2

  t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

and, products

```
class AddColumnsToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
drop_table :products

create_table :products do |t|
    t.string :product_title
    t.text :product_desc
    t.string :product_image_url
    t.decimal :price, precision: 8, scale: 2

    t.timestamps
 end
end
end
```

and, products

```
class AddColumnToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
add_column :products, :department, :string
end
end
```

and, products

```
class AddMoreColumnsToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
add_column :products, :display_on_home_page, :boolean, default: false
add_column :products, :is_highight_product, :boolean, default: false
end
end
```

and, products

```
class RenameIsHighightProductInProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
def up
rename_column :products, :is_highight_product, :is_highlight_product
end

def down
end
end
```

and, products

```
class RenameProductImageUrlInProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
def up
rename_column :products, :product_image_url, :image_url
end

def down
end
end
```

and product images table created

```
class CreateProductImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :product_images do |t|
  t.integer :product_id
  t.string :title
  t.text :description
  t.string :image_file_name
  t.string :image_content_type
  t.integer :image_file_size
  t.datetime :image_updated_at

  t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

and, products

```
class AlterTableProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
def up
end
remove_column :products, :image_url
add_column :products, :product_image_id, :integer
def down
end
end
```

and, product_images

```
class AddColumnToProductImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
add_column :product_images, :image_path, :string
end
end
```

and, product_images

```
class RenameColumnImagePathInProductImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
def up
rename_column :product_images, :image_path, :image_url
end

def down
end
end
```

and, product_images

```
class AddProductTitleColumnToProductImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
add_column :product_images, :product_title, :string
end
end
```

and finally, products

```
class DropPriceFromProductsAndAddPriceToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
def up
end
remove_column :products, :price
add_column :products, :price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
def down
end
end
```

Comment: can you paste the migrations for product and product_image? Adn furthermore I don't think you need the line \@product_image.product_id = \@product.id and again \@product_image.save because if you followed the conventions, ActiveRecord should handle this for you because you are using belongs_to and has_many

Comment: i've added all of the migrations in relation to products and product_images.
as you can probably tell i'm quite new to rails and made lots of mistakes in my tables as I added more to the models.

Comment: by removing thos lines I am able to create an image in the db. but upon checking "sqlite3 -line db/development.sqlite3 "select * from product_images"" the field labelled 'product_id' does not contain the id of the product that its supposed to be linked to, it remains blank

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is going wrong because there is a little too less info in your question. But let me show quickly, how this should be set up (simplified).

new rails app:

```
rails new stack_product
```

creating the models

```
rails g model product
rails g model image
```

You get all this (you have to add the attr_accessible attributes by hand here)

app/models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description

  has_many :images
end
```

app/models/image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :path, :product_id

  belongs_to :product, foreign_key: "product_id"
end
```

db/migrations/20131011195035_create_products.rb

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.primary_key :id
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.string :image_url

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

20131011195421_create_images.rb

```
class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :images do |t|
      t.primary_key :id
      t.integer :product_id
      t.string :name
      t.string :path
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

use rails console in the terminal.

```
rails console
```

the fire:

```
Product.create({title: 'Ford Mustang', description: 'The one and only Shelby'})
...
Image.create({product_id: 1, name: 'Image Mustang', path: '/images/mustang.png'})
Image.create({product_id: 1, name: 'Image Mustang from behind', path: '/images/mustang2.png'})
```

then you can query the objects

```
p = Product.find(1)
Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]] 
=> #<Product id: 1, title: "Ford Mustang", description: "The one and only Shelby",  image_url: nil, created_at: "2013-10-11 20:14:06", updated_at: "2013-10-11 20:14:06">

Image.where("product_id=?", p.id)
Image Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE (product_id=1)
=> [#<Image id: 1, product_id: 1, name: "Image Mustang", path: "/images/mustang.png",  created_at: "2013-10-11 20:14:09", updated_at: "2013-10-11 20:14:09">, #<Image id: 2,  product_id: 1, name: "Image Mustang from behind", path: "/images/mustang2.png", created_at: "2013-10-11 20:14:26", updated_at: "2013-10-11 20:14:26">]
```

So this works fine. If you would create forms for this, you would have one for the products and another one for the images. The images form would have a dropdown with all the products (productname and value with id). The dropdown for the products would be named product_id and then the product's id would be saved in the image table as product_id.

You should maybe scaffold all this to see how it is be done by Rails.